# AxiosError : message: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I have springboot backend application and i'm calling post api of springboot using axios is react but getting error

**and here is the error which im getting in browser console**
[image of error in browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oElJX.png)

**UserService.js**
`

```
import axios from "axios";
import { myAxios } from "./Constant";

export const saveUser =  (user) => {
    return myAxios.post("/user/register-user",user).then((response) => response.data);
}
```

`

**SignUp.js**
`

```
const submitForm = async (event)=>{
  // stopping default behavior of submit
  event.preventDefault()
  
  //console.log('data submitted')
  console.log(signUpData)
  
  // validate form data

  // call server api to submit form data
  saveUser(signUpData)
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp);
    console.log("success log");
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    //console.log("Error log");
  })
```

`
**Springboot REST API Code**
[backend code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncyL7.png)

**CORS configuration**
[backend code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn0Qq.png)

**from postman api is working fine this**

```
{
"userName":"ram",
"userEmail":"ram@gmail.com",
"password":"pwd5",
"about":"ram is a react developer working in xyz"
```

}

Comment: Did you try using it with "await" ?

Comment: Are you running your backend on localhost ??

Comment: @MuhammadMujtabaShafique i have already put await you can see above in code

Comment: @Spyder the backend code is in springboot running in localhost 8080

Comment: @ShubhamNigam

Try this with async and await function

Comment: @ShubhamNigam What is mean it :
export const saveUser = async (user) => {
    return await myAxios.post("/user/register-user",user).then((response) => response.data);
}

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @MuhammadMujtabaShafique actually i have exported this saveUser so that i can call it to another file which you can see above like this 

saveUser(signUpData)
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp);
    console.log("success log");
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    //console.log("Error log");
  })

Comment: This 400 status code has nothing to do with CORS. I'll remove the [tag:cors] tag.

Comment: Try the same request with Postman. It is just your backend fails the validation most likely

Comment: @Spyder as you suggested i have changed the code like this

const submitForm = async (event)=>{
  event.preventDefault()
  await myAxios.post("http://localhost:8080/user/register-user",signUpData)
    .then((response)=>{
      console.log(response);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

// still same issue : AxiosError : message: Request failed with status code 400

Comment: @NikitaChayka from backend side api is working fine im able to post data ...

Comment: The same data you tryin here? Same property names, same values?

Comment: @NikitaChayka yes...

Comment: @NikitaChayka thank you so much as you told me to check that same filed Shubham Nigam im using in react which are declared in backend actually im using some different name in react thats why error is coming

thanks a lot